# Why does [context save:&error] return NO and the error is nil?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

So the question basically is why NSManagedObjectContext returns NO from

```
[context save:&error];
```

and the error is nil?

This is done on the main thread, right after context was created and its persistent store is not nil. And the changes seem to be saved to the database, but according to the apple's reference it's the return value, not the error indicates if the save was successful.

Comment: I've never seen that happen, but it's possible. Do you have more code to show from this. It might help answer the question (for instance, if you're using blocks, you could have an issue with that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is context nil?

If so you're really calling:

```
[nil save:&error]
```

Which will return nil or NO.